# router in vue is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I have added a axios interceptor in my App.vue to catch all status 401, so I can logout users. I am trying to redirect to the login page. I keep getting "Cannot read property '$router' of undefined" not sure what the problem is. Any help? Also is there a better way to handle axios http status errors globally. Instead of checking if status is 400,401 etc on each component that makes a http request.

```
created: function () {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (err) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      if (err.response.status=== 401 ) {

        this.$router.push({ name: 'loginview' })

    }
      throw err;
   });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `this` will not refer to the component instance inside the internal functions. There are various ways to fix this, such as using arrow functions instead.

In the example below I have also removed the `new Promise` as that doesn't appear to be necessary.

```js
created: function () {
  // Using an arrow function preserves the 'this' value
  axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, err => {
    if (err.response.status === 401 ) {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'loginview' })
    }

    // You may not want to return this in the 401 case
    return Promise.reject(err)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do somethig like this:

```
created: function () {
  var router=this.$router;
  axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (err) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      if (err.response.status=== 401 ) {

        router.push({ name: 'loginview' })

    }
      throw err;
   });
  });
}
```